# Coupon to offer discount and free saver delivery, but still allow paid options

Tags: shipping, coupon, discount

I have a discount code set up (FREE20) that offers customers 20% off certain items and free delivery on those items.

The only problem is that I only want to offer free standard delivery, but still give the customer the option to pay for next day delivery. However when the discount code is applied all the shipping options are available for free.

How can I fix this? Or disable the other shipping options when the code is applied?

Answer (score 0):

When you are setting up your Shipping Methods (System -> Configuration -> Shipping Methods) you can select the method that is allowed to be shipped for free.  This config setting can be found under "Free Method" for a majority of shipping types in the US, for our store we specifically set it for both USPS and UPS.

Comment: We are a UK store, so US shipping methods don't help. My shipping methods are currently set up as 5 separate flat rates that the customer can choose from.